# Adding or removing an array from or to a list of array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

I want to do something like this, the code is

```
import numpy as np
import random
a = [np.array([2,4,5]), np.array([3,4,6]), np.array([3,7,8])]
b=np.array([4,6,7])
for i in range(5):
    e = random.choice(a)
    a.remove(e)
    a.append(b)
```

But we can't remove or add arrays like that. I want to remove the array e and add array b to a, so how can I do that?

Comment: One of the weirdest hacks that I use is convert the arrays to strings, and then reevaluate them when needed. Strings are comparable so you can easily almost all default functions on them

Comment: Do you have to remove by value or by index?  `a[2:3] = []` removes an element

Comment: Is there any reason to use value to remove element rather than using index like e = random.choice(range(0,len(a))); a.pop(e) ?

Comment: What is the actual goal of this code?

Comment: Do you understand the error when you try `a.remove(a[1])`?

Comment: `a.pop(1)` is another way of removing an element by index.

Comment: The code is to generate chaos game , I have 4 vertices and I want to choose one of them randomly but the condition is that we can't select the same vertex consecutively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import numpy as np
import random
a = [np.array([2,4,5]), np.array([3,4,6]), np.array([3,7,8])]
b=np.array([4,6,7])
for i in range(5):
    a = list(np.delete(a, random.randint(0,len(a)-1), 0))
    a.append(b)
```

Comment: Thanks...got the solution...Thanks to you... I get something like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/15PZoaU7sekC0Lno7ifpfTYMWi9gQg-fI/view?usp=drivesdk